# How to reach people from R&D industry departments?

Tags: job-search

I'm currently looking for a job in pharma-biotech industry. What is the normal path to contact them? I've noticed people is normally not listed in their company webpages.

Comment: To quote from the [Help Center](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask): "To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where … [...] there is no actual problem to be solved."

Comment: The question has been reformulated

Comment: Does the company have a "careers" page or something similar? If not, continuing to seek a job there is sometimes called "cold calling". Are you asking us how to find a job using this method?

Comment: While I'm having a hard time parsing "How to reach the head of Research and Development industry departments", I gather that you want to bypass nearly everyone in a corporate structure.  If you really want to do this, I just typed "biotech" in to LinkedIn and it auto-corrected to "biotechnology" and populated a number of companies.  Then I looked up "People that work at Monsanto" and their CTO was at the top of the next list.  I suggest against this approach though.

Comment: I modified the question @HireThisMarine to be a bit more relaxed..., now I'm asking about people in general...Anyway, I think it was already answered by Jane S.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer:** You don't :)

It's not people you need to look for on their company web pages, but rather any job postings.  If there are roles available and you get far enough, then you'll be contacted by the relevant people.  Remember, there's a reason *why* they don't list contact details for these people on their websites, which is to prevent them being overwhelmed by potential candidates pestering them about jobs.

These organisations don't just create jobs for the "right" person, the role must exist *first* based on what they perceive to be a business need.  So while perusing their web pages is the right place to start, focus on the "Jobs" section rather than contact details.